# SQL Syntax Error

Tags: sql

I'm getting an incorrect syntax error when I try to execute this query in t-sql.  I'd appreciate any help - I believe the issue is on, or around the ROUND statement.

```
SELECT
    EMPL.employeeid as KEmplID,
    EMPL.PERSONNUM as EmployeeNumber,
    EMPL.PERSONFULLNAME as FullName,
....

FROM
    VP_EMPLOYEE as EMPL,
    VP_PERSON as PRSN,
    (
    SELECT
        TLS.employeeid as EMPLID,
        TLS.applydate as APPLYDATE,
        ROUND((SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,TLS.timeinseconds)) /60/60,1)) AS ElapsedHrs

    FROM
        VP_TOTALS as TLS,
        VP_PAYCODE as PAYCODE



....
```

I am just not quite sure where my issue stems - again, I think it is the round statement but I could be wrong.  I will appreciate any and all help - or suggestions - to make this more efficient or help with the rounding, conversion and sum of the data.

Comment: `FROM
    VP_EMPLOYEE as EMPL,
    VP_PERSON as PRSN,` - doesn't make sense

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky why not?

Comment: @Kermit. Never mind - you're right that could make sense.

Comment: It would be nice to see the full SQL script.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 3):

Incorrect:

```
ROUND((SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,TLS.timeinseconds)) /60/60,1)) AS ElapsedHrs
```

Corrected (parenthesis placement):

```
ROUND((SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,TLS.timeinseconds)) /60/60),1) AS ElapsedHrs
                                                   ^
```